# $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, modal

No consigo hacer ver un modal, según he leido, este error puede ser por dos razones, la primera que este duplicada la llamada a jquery y la segunda que jquery cargue después de boostrap, no soy muy experto pero lo he repasado y no veo el fallo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.0/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></script> <!-- Estilo botones css---->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/scanner.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" href="//gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

     PlnDir("html/partes.html");//Cargo la  pagina de partes en la principal

}); //Fin de document ready

</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <!-- Mi Cabecera-->

<table class=" table table-sm  text-center">
    <thead >
      <tr class="header">
        <th><label  class=" font-weight-bold ">Fecha</label></th>
        <th><label  class=" font-weight-bold ">Nombre</label></th>
        <th><label  class=" font-weight-bold ">Camión</label></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


  </table>

    <div id="principal"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/funciones.js"></script> <!---------Mis funciones en js---------->
    <script src="./js/quagga.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/sum().js"></script>     <!--Plugin Para hacer sumas en tablas--> 
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/natural.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script><!--- Esto hace que los nuevos targ de html5 se visualicen bien en navegadores antiguos--->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-filestyle/2.1.0/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.11/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>

    <!---Botones de tablas--->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.40/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.40/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Y Esta es la funcion donde llamo al modal.

```
$('#tbl_Partes tbody').off('click', 'button.delParte');
        $('#tbl_Partes tbody').on('click', 'button.delParte', function () {
            var idParte = tblPartes.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
            $("#mdConfirm").modal('show'); //Aqui llamo al modal


            var modalConfirm = function(callback){
                $("#btn-confirm").on("click", function(){
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('show');
                });

                $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function(){
                    callback(true);
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('hide');
                });

                $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function(){
                    callback(false);
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('hide');
                });
            };

        modalConfirm(function(confirm){
          if(confirm){
            //Acciones si el usuario confirma
            delParte(idParte['id']);
          }else{
            //Acciones si el usuario no confirma

          }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sube todas las librerias dentro del head, no pongas librerias en un lado y despues en otro a menos de que estes usando un layout o masterpage.
Engloba tu evento de click dentro de tu load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tbl_Partes tbody').off('click', 'button.delParte');
        $('#tbl_Partes tbody').on('click', 'button.delParte', function () {
            var idParte = tblPartes.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
            $("#mdConfirm").modal('show'); //Aqui llamo al modal


            var modalConfirm = function(callback){
                $("#btn-confirm").on("click", function(){
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('show');
                });

                $("#modal-btn-si").on("click", function(){
                    callback(true);
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('hide');
                });

                $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function(){
                    callback(false);
                    $("#mdConfirm").modal('hide');
                });
            };

        modalConfirm(function(confirm){
          if(confirm){
            //Acciones si el usuario confirma
            delParte(idParte['id']);
          }else{
            //Acciones si el usuario no confirma

          }
        });

    });

}); //Fin de document ready
```

En realidad necesitas tantas librerias? Acuerdate que estaras usando los recursos del usuario poniendo tantas librerias inecesarias.
Trata de dejar solamente las librerias que contengan .min.js/.min.css Estas librerias estan optimizadas

Si en realidad necesitas tantas librerias, trata de darle un orden.
Datatables es muy enfadoso si lo usas mal, si hay un error de datatables puede que te este generando un excepcion lo que puede provocar que tu modal no funcione bien

Comment: Mala idea para el rendimiento, que vayan en el header sólo algunos, no todos.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera me ha funcionado correctamente. No tengo claro cual era el problema, he vuelvo a una versión anterior de bootstrap que tenia y ya me funciona.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

     <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/scanner.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
 </head>
 <body>
 <script>
 

</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <!-- Mi Cabecera-->
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/quagga.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="./js/funciones.js"></script> <!---------Mis funciones en js---------->
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/api/sum().js"></script>     <!--Plugin Para hacer sumas en tablas--> 
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script><!---- Es necesario para el datetimepicker--->
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/natural.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script><!--- Esto hace que los nuevos targ de html5 se visualicen bien en navegadores antiguos--->
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> 
    
  </body>
</html>
```